# url generate multiple time in pagination

Tags: php

My pagination is working good .But problem is that when I click on pagination then its does not generate new link .Its add a page id with old  link .Like
videos.php?page=2page=3 and if again i cliked on  4th number pagination .Its show like this  videos.php?page=2page=3page=4.

```
<?php
$limit = 20;  
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  
    $sql = "$que LIMIT $start_from, $limit";  
    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql); 
    $result = mysql_query($que); 
    $total_bookss = mysql_num_rows($result); 

     $full_linkp = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
     $full_linkEx=explode('&page',$full_linkp);
    $full_link=$full_linkEx[0];

    if($total_bookss>$limit){                   
     $total_records = $total_bookss;  
     $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  
    $pagLink = "<nav><ul class='pagination'>";

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
    //$pagLink .= "<li><a href='$full_link.php&page=". $i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
      $pagLink .= "<li><a href='$full_link&page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";  
    }
    //show pagination variable
    $show_pagination=$pagLink . "</ul></nav>";}
?>
<script>
    jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq('.pagination').pagination({
    items: <?php echo $total_records;?>,
    itemsOnPage: <?php echo $limit;?>,
    cssStyle: 'light-theme',
    currentPage : <?php echo $page;?>,
    hrefTextPrefix : '<?=$full_link?>page='
    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that

```
<?php
$limit = 20;  
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  
    $start_from = ($page-1) * $limit;  
    $sql = "$que LIMIT $start_from, $limit";  
    $rs_result = mysql_query($sql); 
    $result = mysql_query($que); 
    $total_bookss = mysql_num_rows($result); 

     $full_linkp = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
     $full_linkEx=explode('?page',$full_linkp);
    $full_link=$full_linkEx[0];

    if($total_bookss>$limit){                   
     $total_records = $total_bookss;  
     $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  
    $pagLink = "<nav><ul class='pagination'>";

    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
    //$pagLink .= "<li><a href='$full_link.php&page=". $i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
      $pagLink .= "<li><a href='$full_link?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";  
    }
    //show pagination variable
    $show_pagination=$pagLink . "</ul></nav>";}
?>

<script>
    jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq('.pagination').pagination({
    items: <?php echo $total_records;?>,
    itemsOnPage: <?php echo $limit;?>,
    cssStyle: 'light-theme',
    currentPage : <?php echo $page;?>,
    hrefTextPrefix : '<?=$full_link?>?page='
    });
    });
</script>
```